# Where are ms paint icons stored?

Tags: windows, icons, microsoft-paint

In which file (.dll, .exe or similar) are icons (such as the pen or the eraser ) stored? To be clear, I mean the new, modern icons - not the ones from earlier versions of windows.[image]

I didn't have any luck in finding them in either mspaint.exe, imageres.dll or shel32.dll (using IconsExtract), so I figured that maybe someone knows where they are.

A general solution for finding icons for any application would also be appreciated.

Comment: Which Operating System?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In earlier Windows 10 versions, the resources are managed in MUI files in
System32 folder. So, the MSPaint icons can be found in this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\en-US\mspaint.exe.mui
```

From Windows 10 version 1903 aka. May 2019 Update, those resources are moved to
MUN files in SystemResources folder. So, the MSPaint icons can be found in this:

```
C:\Windows\SystemResources\mspaint.exe.mun
```

The `en-US` is the default system language. It will vary if system language isdifferent. Open the file in any resource editing tool, for example [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)
or it's [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/resource-hacker/) to view the resources. The required icons are stored
in image folder.

[image: icons-in-resource-hacker]

The easiest way is to extract those icons from that `mspaint.exe.mun` file with
[7ZIP](https://www.7-zip.org/). Then rename every file with ICO extension.

[image: icons-in-7zip]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. I have just one more question: How to extract those images without losing their transparency (cause currently they get extracted with a dark grey background)?

Comment: @YanB. That's why I added the 7zip method. Use 7zip to extract the icon.