# MS Paint/Wordpad 'Open', 'Save', and 'Save as' icon locations

Tags: windows, icons, extract

This is most definitely the wrong forum to post this on, but I couldn't work out where else this would go [on this list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology).

Where on Windows are [these three icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASbEB.png) saved?

Using [IconsExtract](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html), I've looked through `C:\Windows\system32\*.*`, as well as `C:\Windows\SystemResources\*.*` to little success. `wmploc.DLL` does happen to contain the 'Save' icon, but nothing else came up.
One can also imagine how difficult it is to get proper results when searching for "Open file icon" or "Save as icon" online.

These icons can be found in MS Paint and WordPad's 'File' context menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are ms paint icons stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1491798/where-are-ms-paint-icons-stored)

Comment: Those are not the icons I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this first:** Most icons are stored in C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll and C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll

You can access the icons in these two DLL files when you use the Change Icon function in the properties of a file or app.

I tried this here and you will see many icons.   Use the Browse function when you Change Icon

Any other icons are part of the actual program or app.

**Then for MS Paint:** its icons are store in C:\Windows\SystemResources in a file called mspaint.exe.mun

You can open this MUN file with Resource Hacker.  This may help you.

Then if all the above fails to assist, the icons are proprietary to the app itself.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I looked through `C:\Windows\system32\*.*`, meaning those 2 files are included. The icons are also not part of `mspaint.exe`.

Comment: In my post, I noted that icons not stored here are the app itself and not likely obtainable if that is the case

Comment: The icons for MS Paint are in a file called mspaint.exe.mun in C:\windows \SystemRescources  . This may help you.