# Where are mspaint icons stored?

Tags: windows, icons, microsoft-paint

Where are these mspaint icons stored? I'm trying to find them in Windows XP.

[image]

Comment: Look in shell32.dll to see if they might be there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are ms paint icons stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1491798/where-are-ms-paint-icons-stored)

Comment: The duplicate notes precisely NOT the icons listed in this question, and the answer is to a different DLL. I do not believe the suggested duplicate is actually duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows executables, icons may be stored in the executable itself or in another *resource* file. For MS Paint in Windows 10, for example, the images are not in the executable, *mspaint.exe*, but in the resource *mspaint.exe.mun*.

To view them, use a tool such as free [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/#download).

[image: mspaine.exe.mun in Resource Hacker]

Note that there are *many* images stored there as *IMAGE*, *Bitmap*, *Icon*, and *Icon Group*, as well as cursors. For example, the cup/brush image is in *Icon Group*.

To find those icons in Windows XP, download a resource viewer, search in the Windows folder for *any* file with *paint* in the name, and open in the viewer. Look at the largest files first, as smaller ones do not have images.